# Multiple images of same mesh without duplicate triangle transfers

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I take multiple images of the same mesh using OpenGL, GLEW and GLFW. The mesh (triangles) doesn't change in each shot, only the `ModelViewMatrix` does.

Here's the important code of my mainloop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_images; i++) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    /* set GL_MODELVIEW matrix depending on i */
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (Triangle &t : mesh) {
        for (Point &p : t) {
            glVertex3f(p.x, p.y, p.z);
        }
    }
    glReadPixels(/*...*/) // get picture and store it somewhere
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}
```

As you can see, I set/transfer the triangle vertices for each shot I want to take. Is there a solution in which I only need to transfer them once? My mesh is quite large, so this transfer takes quite some time.

Comment: Upload the mesh to a vertex buffer object. In the end: Don't use the fixed function pipeline (it's outdated since ages) and move to core profile. There you are obligated to use vertex buffer objects.

Comment: You use old OpenGL API. Try to use modern API. I know there are a lot of books about old OpenGL and it is hard to understand, where is right way to study OpenGL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the year 2016 you **must not** use `glBegin`/`glEnd`. No way. Use [Vertex Array Obejcts](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) instead; and use custom [vertex](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader) and/or [geometry](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) shaders to reposition and modify your vertex data. Using these techniques, you will upload your data to the GPU once, and then you'll be able to draw the same mesh with various transformations.

Here is an outline of how your code may look like:

```
// 1. Initialization.
// Object handles:
GLuint vao;
GLuint verticesVbo;
// Generate and bind vertex array object.
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
// Generate a buffer object.
glGenBuffers(1, &verticesVbo);
// Enable vertex attribute number 0, which
// corresponds to vertex coordinates in older OpenGL versions.
const GLuint ATTRIBINDEX_VERTEX = 0;
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBINDEX_VERTEX);
// Bind buffer object.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesVbo);
// Mesh geometry. In your actual code you probably will generate
// or load these data instead of hard-coding.
// This is an example of a single triangle.
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, -9.0f,
    0.0f, 0.1f, -9.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, -9.0f
};
// Determine vertex data format.
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBINDEX_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
// Pass actual data to the GPU.
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*3*3, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// Initialization complete - unbinding objects.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

// 2. Draw calls.
while(/* draw calls are needed */) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    // Set transformation matrix and/or other
    // transformation parameters here using glUniform* calls.
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbinding just as an example in case if some other code will bind something else later.
}
```

And a vertex shader may look like this:

```
layout(location=0) in vec3 vertex_pos;
uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix; // Assuming you set this before glDrawArrays.

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(vertex_pos, 1.0f);
}
```

Also take a look at [this page](http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/) for a good modern accelerated graphics book.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew, that I was using quite ancient OpenGL. Your post motivated me to switch to the modern style.

Answer (score 0):

@BDL already commented that you should abandon the immediate mode drawing calls (glBegin … glEnd) and switch to Vertex Array drawing (glDrawElements, glDrawArrays) that fetch their data from Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs). @Sergey mentioned *Vertex Array Objects* in his answer, but those are actually state containers for VBOs.

A very important thing you have to understand – and the way you asked your question it's apparently something you're not aware of, yet – is, that OpenGL does not deal with "meshes", "scenes" or the like. OpenGL is just a drawing API. It draws points… lines… and triangles… one at a time… with no connection between them whatsoever. That's it. So when you show multiple views of the "same" thing, you *must* **draw** it several times. There's no way around this.

Most recent versions of OpenGL support multiple viewport rendering, but it still takes a geometry shader to multiply the geometry into several pieces to be drawn.